# How to show always F# type like VSCode in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

## VSCode

[image: VSCode]

## Visual Studio 2019

[image: Visual Studio 2019]

What is this feature called?
Can I use this feature in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called "Code Lens" and you can enable it in `Tools -> Options`, then select `Text Editor -> F# -> Code Lens`

But it only works in `*.fs` files for some reason, not in `*.fsx`